# Windows 7 pc opening port 139 from random IP addresses

Tags: windows-7, networking, tcp

When I run CurrPorts (a TCP monitoring tool for nirsoft) I get the expected output plus entries that I do not understand. My LAN is 192.168.1.x. My pc is set to a static IP of 192.168.1.12. But I find IP addresses like 192.168.42.1, 192.168.56.1 and 192.168.92.1

```
System  4   TCP 139 netbios-ssn 192.168.42.1            0.0.0.0     Listening   System                  N/A             1/3/2016 9:33:46 PM             
System  4   TCP 139 netbios-ssn 192.168.56.1            0.0.0.0     Listening   System                  N/A             1/3/2016 9:33:46 PM             
System  4   TCP 139 netbios-ssn 192.168.92.1            0.0.0.0     Listening   System
```

Why are net bios connections (port 139) listed from IP addresses OUTSIDE my subnet? I just have a simple LAN behind a regular router. I get similar data from netstat as well as TCPview.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be? They are using TCP/IP which is not limited to a single subnet.

Comment: @RonMaupin: Because the listed addresses are from the "Local" column, so they can only be addresses assigned to a local interface (i.e. on the same computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes virtualization software/VPN programs will add adapters. Open up a command prompt and run "ipconfig" to see if those addresses match any of the adapters.

Comment: bingo!                                                
`Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:            
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.92.1            
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:            
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.1        
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:              
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1`